# bootstrap php includes with sidebar

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, include

Okay, so this is a first for me. Using php includes.

The problem I'm running into is that the content for the page is being pushed down onto another row when i include the sidebar.php.

This is the code for the side bar. The content means pretty much nothing now, because I'll probably change a couple of things. But the col-md-3 class is the thing that most confusing, because it should in theory work in tandem with the pages col-md class.

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
```

```
<!--- Start of accordion ---->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel-group col-md-3 panel_custom_group" id="accordian">
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#apparel" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">APPAREL <span class="panel_plus">+</span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="apparel">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a href="#allproducts" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#apparel">ALL PRODUCTS <span class="panel_plus">+</span></a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="allproducts">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#headwear" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">HEADWEAR<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus side_bar_glyph"></span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="headwear">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#bags" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">BAGS<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="bags">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#gifts" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">GIFTS<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="gifts">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#brands" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">BRANDS<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="brands">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#categories" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">CATEGORIES<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="categories">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-custom">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a href="#specials" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian">SPECIALS<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="specials">
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>        


<!--- end of accordian ---->
```

And this is the page i inserted it into.

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
```

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <p>Home > Registration</p>
</div>
```

```
<section class="container registr_middle col-md-6">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/become_a_partner_banner.jpg" title="Become a Partner" alt="Become a Partner" />
</section>
```

```
<section class="registr_side col-md-3">
    <div> 
        <h3>Partner Registration</h3>
        <p>Becoming an Altitude partner can be a life changing event. As Altitude Leisurewear is a sincerely TRADE ONLY SUPPLIER the criteria to become an Altitude agent.<br />
        In order to register as an approved distributor of the Altitude Leisure Wear brand, you will be required to complete the following documentation.<br />
        Once completed, the following information must be signed and faxed to: <strong>086 580 0596</strong>.<br /></p>
        <p class="background_para">Any incomplete application forms will be disregarded</p>
        <ul>
            <li>A signed copy of our client profile document</li>
            <li>A signed copy of our standard terms and conditions</li>
            <li>A copy of company Registration(CK Form)</li>
            <li>A company profile verifying that our primary business is the resale of corporate and promotional products.</li>
            <li>A copy of your business card</li>
            <li>A copy of your ID document</li>
            <li>An invoice os order to a client or from a supplier showing that you re-sell sorporate wear</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Please complete the application form below to register with Altitude Leisure Wear. A Customer Care representative will forward you the documentation that needs to be completed in           order to do the verification of your status.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

So shouldn't the side bar's width work with the main content of the pages width. They both add up to 12 (for the grid system).

[image: An image for a better understanding]

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoudn't use `.container` and `.col-md-6` on the same element.

It should look like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">First half</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Second half</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I'm using the .container class to center both of them. the col-md-6 is there because it has to only take up that much space. the sidebar needs to be next to main content with the image The things is that it is fairly easy to get what i'm going for without using php includes, but with it, the problem arises.

Comment: Looks like u must be missing some closing `</div>` then.

Comment: nope. double checked that too. i need to make the '<?php include('header.php'); ?>' be treated like a div that shares the same '.container' 'div'  as the page content im sharing it with

Comment: The paste it into that container div, for example: `<div class="container"><?php include('head.php'); ?>...`

Comment: fixed it bro I'm going to post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I let it work by putting a 'div' with the class of 'col-md-3' around the include line and then wrapped all the contents in a container div. I then removed the 'col-md-3' in the sidebar.php file.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <?php include('sidebar.php'); ?>
 </div>
```